# 'Mortgage One's Future' Meaning

Tags: idiom-meaning

What does 'mortgage one's future' mean? It's [in this presidential address](https://youtu.be/zMSXDuK6YsM?t=244). I think it's used figuratively and means 'to put something at risk/endanger'. Am I right? What synonyms would you suggest?

Comment: The Webster's definition [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mortgage) contains / explains the expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, just because the dictionary quotes a common phrase about mortgaging one’s future, it doesn’t really explain this metaphor. If I mortgage my future, where do I go to get the money?

Comment: @Xanne 'put an advance claim / liability on'? I'm not so sure. However, if this easily-available reference (and a definition or two of 'mortgage' in the unbroadened sense ...) were added, the question would at least contain necessary research. However, if your answer (or indeed  bootface's guess) is actually correct, the question hinges on identification of an actual intended sense as used by an author, requiring knowledge of the larger context, which moves it into 'literature' or perhaps 'politics'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Research may be inadequate; but to me this is an idiom that is not obviously understandable from its component words. Where is the contract? Where is the asset against which funds are borrowed? In MMM (modern monetary theory), there’s an argument that repayment (of what, by whom? is no problem. It seems to be such a conventional phrase that it’s not even recognized as a metaphor.

Comment: @Xanne thank you for the explanation, I think I'm getting it now. This phrase is really not so obvious and easily understandable from its components

Answer (score 1):

A mortgage is a legal contract that is not easily broken. The term means that if you make a particular decision, the effect is binding and you will be paying for this decision for a long time.  It's not necessarily bad. It simply means think carefully before you commit to something.

Comment: Is there any synonym to explain the meaning of the phrase? To undermine? To put something in question?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it means to take some advantage now that will have to be paid for later, with a risk of losing something of great value if the "repayment" can't be made. Similar to how if we can't pay the mortgage on a home, the home can be re-possessed by the lender.

Comment: The actual benefit of a mortgage (the possibility of having one's own house, family ...)  may well not be outweighed by the extra monetary price one ends up paying. There _is_ an incalculable risk involved.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, sorry, I've re-stated it.

Comment: That's quite understandable in financial terms, but not very clear how someone can take advantage of their children's future though

Comment: @Rita, for example, by allowing industry to pollute the environment, we improve the economy today, but in the future we (or our children) will have to deal with the clean-up or the economic impact of climate change.

Answer (score 0):

“Mortgaging our children’s future” in the context of a presidential address refers to borrowing by the federal government. The money is spent today, but will have to be repaid in the future.

The relevant measure is the debt held by the public in relation to the productivity of the economy, usually as measured by the Gross Domestic Product. As this ratio increases, the demands of debt repayment in comparison to what will be earned in the future increase.